# Differing number of "things" in mammals

Tags: evolution, anatomy

I'm not a biology expert, but I have often wondered about the following facts of life:

All mammals have precisely 5 fingers on each of our 4 extremities. Granted, some may not be seen, but the bone structure of 5 fingers is there in all mammals, from whales to bats to humans. This, I guess, tells me that changing the number of finger bones is, genetically speaking, fairly difficult (as it never happened during the evolution of mammals.

On the other hand, pigs have 12 nipples, dogs have 6, and humans have 2. Pigs have 44 teeth, dogs have 42, and humans (the lucky ones) have 32. This, I guess, means that it is easy to change the number of teeth in a species, as this happened often during the evolution of mammals.

My question is this: What is the reason behind this discrepancy? Why is it that much easier to change one thing and not the other? And a subquestion: why do we still have 32 teeth when the 4 wisdom teeth cause nothing but trouble? Wouldn't having only 28 teeth be an evolutionary advantage?

Comment: The number of fingers is not really same for all mammals: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-toed_ungulate#/media/File:Artiodactyla_feet.png) picture. It shows limb bones of some [even-toed ungulates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-toed_ungulate). And whales have totally lost the hindlimb. So your presupposition is not correct.

Comment: The genes, and the complexity of the genetic networks, underlying each trait are not necessarily the same.